# C++ Lambda Function closure - memory issue

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm new to cpp and trying to work with lambda function. I have a counter which I'm trying to increment inside a lambda function and outside of it. I'm seeing some weird memory errors which I cannot make sense of. Here is the flow in which I'm working with this counter. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong.

```
bool SomeClass::func() {
     int64_t counter = 0;

     //some loop logic {
         counter++;
     }


     auto lamb = [this, &counter]() {
        //some logic
        counter++;
     }

     someotherFunction(data, lamb); // this function will execute the lambda

}
```

Comment: As this function is written it *should* work - because if `lamb` is executed inside `someotherFunction` then `counter`  will still be in scope. If, however, `someotherFunction` is *storing* the lambda, and later, after `func` has returned, the lambda is executed, then you have a dangling reference problem.

Comment: But looking at the comments below, it seems that if someotherFunction's execution outlives func execution then it will fail right?

Comment: The point is you're calling `someotherFunction` from *inside* `func`, which means it *can't* outlive `func`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that C++ lambdas are not able to solve the "[upwards funarg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funarg_problem)" case, i.e. when a local variable is captured by reference by a lambda that survives the "owner" of the local (because it's stored somewhere or because it returned as function result).

What C++ does when a lambda captures a variable by reference is just storing the address of the referenced variable in a context structure that is used by the lambda code.

The variable itself however in your case is a local and lives in the stack frame where the lambda was created. If the lambda object is just called during the execution of `someOtherFunction` then things are fine, but if the lambda is instead **stored away** and survives the stack frame that created it (or to be more precise that created the captured variable referenced in the lambda), when it's executed will reference a variable that doesn't exist any more (undefined behavior).

Solving the "upwards funarg" problem in the general case requires a garbage collector, and C++ doesn't have one.

What you can do in some cases is capturing "by value", so the lambda will have its own private copy:

```
foo([counter]() mutable { counter++; })
```

In this case however if you want to change the captured copy you also need to use the `mutable` keyword because ... well, just because this is what C++ requires if you want to modify a captured copy (captured copies are otherwise `const` objects in the body of the lambda).

Unfortunately if you need to share captured variables for example with two lambdas (e.g. creating both an "incrementer" and a "decrementer" on the same captured variable) the using a copy is not viable.
What you can do for this is capturing by value a `std::shared_ptr` to the variable and this will correctly replace the garbage collector for simple cases (not in the case of reference loops, however).

Comment: How do I get around this issue? Is there a way to pass by value the local variable to lambda then?

Comment: When you mentioned to use a shared pointer, were you saying to do something like: `auto pin = std::make_shared<int>(counter);` and capturing `pin` by value? @6502

Comment: @Anzurio: yes. Capturing a `shared_ptr` by value is ok, provided the lambda lifetime itself is not handled by shared pointers that can potentially create a loop of references with captured objects (C++ doesn't provide a garbage collector so abandoned refcounted loops are leaks).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a practical approach to 6502's excellent answer:

```
auto make_counter(int initial) {
  return [initial] (void) mutable {
    return ++initial;
  };
}
```

Here, the local variable (actually it's a function parameter, but that's not of importance) is captured by value, meaning there's a copy of it "inside" the every object of that lambda. In order to be able to increment the counter the lambda must allow modifications to it's captured variables, thus the `mutable`.